# How can I change the color of my DataGridHeader from my checkbox when this is activated?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid, wpf-controls

I have a DatGrid and I want that when you activate the CheckBox you can change the color setting of my DataGrid header in the xaml code. I know that it works with trigger, but my CheckBox is outside the stack panel where my DataGrid is inside but there are in the same Dockpanel and I don't know exactly how and where to place the trigger event.

A part from my Code:

My DataGrid:

```
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <!--Design kopfzeile-->
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#292F3B"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightBlue"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,0" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Border Background="#242A36">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1"
                                        CornerRadius="6"
                                        Background="#2D2D30"
                                        Padding="10,0,0,0"
                                        Margin="2">
                                        <ContentPresenter/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>


                </Style>

                <!--Deaktivieren Des rowheader-->
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                </Style>

                <!--Cellen Design-->
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#292F3B"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightBlue"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,0" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                <Border Background="#242A36">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1"
                                        CornerRadius="6"
                                        Background="#292F3B"
                                        Padding="10,0,0,0"
                                        Margin="2">
                                        <ContentPresenter/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#454F5D"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>

                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

        </DataGrid>
```

And Here is my Button:

```
<StackPanel>
  <Dockpanel>
        <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=lbUsers,Path=DataContext.IsChecked}" x:Name="checkBox" Content="CheckBox" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}"  Width="130" Height="24" RenderTransformOrigin="0.662,0.494"/>
  </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `DataTrigger` instead of `Trigger`, you can access the CheckBox that is defined outside of your DataGrid.  Also, it looks like you've mistakenly hardcoded your backgrounds inside of your ControlTemplate, so depending on which Border Background you want to target, you will need to set that background to a TemplateBinding.

Here's an example:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1"
                    CornerRadius="6"
                    Background="#2D2D30"
                    Padding="10,0,0,0"
                    Margin="2">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Trigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=checkBox,Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Example Result:

[image]

Comment: But did you know why my IsMouseOver effect only works if my checkbox is on false?

Comment: This is due to "order of operation" in how the XAML code is read by the WPF interpreter.  If you want the IsMouseOver effect to work even when checkbox is true, then you just have to cut the IsMouseOver effect code, and then paste it AFTER the DataTrigger code.